# what are the usage of equalprg and formatprg

Tags: formatting

If I want to format a few lines, should I choose `equalprg` (using `=` operator) or `formatprg` (using `gq` operator)?

Both of them are for some kind of formatting. But what are the differences.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From `:help equalprg`:

> ```
> 'equalprg' 'ep'               string  (default "")
>                       global or local to buffer |global-local|
>       External program to use for "=" command. ...
> ```

From `:help =`:

> ```
> ={motion}               Filter {motion} lines through the external program
>                         given with the 'equalprg' option.  When the 'equalprg'
>                         option is empty (this is the default), use the
>                         internal formatting function |C-indenting| and
>                         |'lisp'|.  But when 'indentexpr' is not empty, it will
>                         be used instead |indent-expression|.  When Vim was
>                         compiled without internal formatting then the "indent"
>                         program is used as a last resort.
> ```

I agree that it would be nice if the "intent" of the motion was written more clearly, but it does seem relatively clear that the intent of `=` and thus `equalprg` is indentation.

---

Similarly we can find from `:help formatprg` and `:help gq` that this is a more general purpose formatting feature. It allows to use external programs or internal methods based on the `formatexpr` and `formatprg` settings. With internal formatting it typically just reflows text within a given textwidth, i.e. the `textwidth` setting.

Comment: for vim scripts, what does `gq` do? It results in weird text (lines joined)

Comment: @LiuSha if `formatexpr` and `formatprg` are empty, then Vim formats the lines as if they were normal text. So the lines are joined to make a paragraph (width subject to `textwidth`, etc.).

Comment: @LiuSha which, to add to muru’s comment, makes `gq` bad for code without a good `formatexpr` or `formatprg`